# Is there a way that multiple jTextArea can share scrollpane in Java- Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a way that a scrollpane from another jTextArea can control another jTextArea to scroll upwards and downwards?

[image]

They may not be the same in width but they will have the same lines of rows. If one jTextArea has more lines than the other then empty lines will be added to the second jTextArea to match them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **jScrollPane1** and **jScrollPane2** are the 2 scrollpanes of your 2 jTextareas respectievley,
with below code you can implement your requirements.

```
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
jTextArea2 = new JTextArea();

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);
.
.
.
.

JScrollBar verticalScrollBar1 = jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar();

verticalScrollBar1.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

     @Override
     public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            JScrollBar vertical = jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar();
            vertical.setValue(e.getValue());
     }
});
```

Comment: I have followed the code you gave, it does not seem to work. I have pasted it to the public class "test" extends javax.swing.JFrame {   } where its has the  "initComponents();" in it. I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: @Red does not work meaning ? As you are using the netbeans drag and drop, unable to edit the code or is it giving any error or no change in the behaviour ? Give more details.